# Why does rotating QImage increase its size?

Tags: qt, qimage, qpixmap

I'm trying to convert an 280x480 image rendered from a textEdit to mono format (1-bit per pixel).

When I convert the image without rotating it produces an 16800-bytes image as expected.

But when I rotate the image 90 degress, the size of the mono image changes to 17280.

```
    QPixmap pixmap( ui->textEdit->rect().size() );
    ui->textEdit->render( &pixmap, QPoint(), QRegion( rectangle ) );

    //QPixmap rotated = pixmap.transformed( QTransform().rotate( 90 ) );
    // if changed 'pixmap' with 'rotated', size changes
    QImage image( pixmap.toImage() );

    QImage monoImg = image.convertToFormat( QImage::Format_Mono );
    qDebug() << monoImg.sizeInBytes();
```

What does cause this change in size and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 3):

The scan line in an image is typically padded to a four byte boundary, i.e. [`QImage::bytesPerLine`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html#bytesPerLine) will return a multiple of four.

You original image is 280 rows by 480 columns and 1 bit per pixel.

```
bytes per scan line = 480 / 8 = 60
```

60 is a multiple of 4 so no padding is necessary.

When you rotate the image you get 480 rows of 280 columns.

```
bytes per scan line = 280 / 8 = 35
```

35 isn't a multiple of of 4 and will be rounded up to 36.  Hence you get an extra 480 bytes in your image.

Note that this behaviour is fairly typical of image formats in general and is not specific to `QImage`.

**Edit:** Your question was...

> Can you please tell me how to get rid of these extra padding bytes? I
> need that the result byte array have only 16800 bytes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <QImage>
#include <QTransform>

int main ()
{
  QImage image(480, 280, QImage::Format_Mono);
  std::cout << "initial " << image.width() << "x" << image.height()
            << " image requires " << image.sizeInBytes() << " bytes\n";

  image = image.transformed(QTransform().rotate(90));
  std::cout << "rotated " << image.width() << "x" << image.height()
            << " image requires " << image.sizeInBytes() << " bytes\n";

  /*
   * Format is QImage::Format_Mono so we only need 1 bit per pixel.  Adjust
   * accordingly for other formats.
   */
  auto required_bits_per_pixel = 1;
  auto required_bytes_per_line = (CHAR_BIT - 1 + required_bits_per_pixel * image.width()) / CHAR_BIT;

  /*
   * Allocate buffer big enough for required data (no padding) and copy data one
   * scan line at a time without padding into the buffer.
   */
  std::unique_ptr<uchar[]> buf(new uchar[required_bytes_per_line * image.height()]);
  for (int y = 0; y < image.height(); ++y)
    std::copy(image.constScanLine(y), image.constScanLine(y) + required_bytes_per_line,
              buf.get() + y * required_bytes_per_line);
  QImage compacted_image(buf.get(), image.width(), image.height(), required_bytes_per_line,
                         QImage::Format_Mono);
  std::cout << "rotated and compacted " << compacted_image.width() << "x"
            << compacted_image.height() << " image requires " << compacted_image.sizeInBytes()
            << " bytes\n";
}
```

The above example assumes the `std::unique_ptr` `buf` will remain in scope for the lifetime of `compacted_image`.  If that can't be guaranteed then you need to release the block managed by `compacted_image` and supply a suitable clean-up function...

```
  QImage compacted_image(buf.release(), image.width(), image.height(), required_bytes_per_line,
                         QImage::Format_Mono,
                         [](void *p){ delete [] reinterpret_cast<uchar *>(p); });
```

Using the above code I get the output...

```
initial 480x280 image requires 16800 bytes
rotated 280x480 image requires 17280 bytes
rotated and compacted 280x480 image requires 16800 bytes
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfect explanation. This clarifies why the size changes. Can you please tell me how to get rid of these extra padding bytes? I need that the result byte array have only 16800 bytes.

Comment: Many thanks @G.M. for the code. It produced a 16800-byte array as you said. But I'm not sure if the result is correct. Please check my update in the question.

Comment: Sorry but the last update doesn't appear to have anything to do with the original question.  It should probably be a separate post.